# How to move the focus to the next component in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

Can anyone tell me how to move the focus to the next component in the screen?

I have one verticalmanager with verticalscroll.  This vertical field manager consists of an edit field with approximately 100 lines of data.  Below this vertical field manager I have one button. If I want to move my focus to that button it means I have to pass through all those 100 lines in that edit field.

Is there another way to pass the focus to the button directly by clicking a single button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Richard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298192/how-to-move-focus-to-next-component-in-blackberry/1299901#1299901) and your comment, I think the correct way to set the focus on the submit button when the `ESC` key is pressed in the edit field is as follows:

```
public boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time)
{
  if (key==Characters.ESCAPE)
  {
    submit.setFocus(); 
  }

  return super.keyChar(key, status, time); 
}
```

***Note:*** The use of the `ESCAPE` key might not be the best option. You might want to check if a modifier key (such as Alt) is pressed by checking the `status` argument and set the focus in that case. You are advised to use your discernment when using this code.

Comment: ESCAPE may not be the best choice since it is also used to close screens. Perhaps using status to also select on Alt status.

If as the code implies the button is to submit the data, there are two solutions that would bring the UI more in line with the standard blackberry interface semantics:

1) create a menu with a submit option
2) override onSave for the screen to change the dialog to Submit (instead of save), Discard, Cancel

Comment: Yes, I realize that ESCAPE might not be the best choice. However, the original poster mentioned in a comment that he was using ESCAPE for this purpose and that is why I wrote it like that. I can edit the post to clarify that though.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to extend one of the containers of the edit field, process key presses looking for the key press you select (it will have to be one not consumed by the edit field). When received call the setFocus() method on the button.

Comment: Hi richard, thanks for ur idea but i already tried this idea.But when i am implementing this idea i can switch to button directly but if i want to edit anything in that editfield then i could not able to do that.Here i have typed the code which i used to use swith to button by pressing "ESC" key.

public boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) 
     {
        if(key==Characters.ESCAPE)
        {
          
           submit.setFocus();
        } 
        return true;
     }

Answer (score 0):

You could make the field with the 100 lines of text unfocusable.  When it is unfocusable, and you scroll over it, the cursor should skip the 100 lines, and go straight to the button at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

There are options:

- use navigationMove (if dx > some value) if edit field not in edit mode
- use menu instead of buttons
- use hotkeys
- use paging in list so there will be no scrolling